# Select values in given sequential numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sequence, generate-series

I'd like to write a query to retrieve users' `id` whose `birthyear` is in current year or all the years which have increment of -12 from `Health_User` table. Take this year for example, it would be users who were born in 2018, 2006, 1994, 1982... I want the query to be general enough to be used in any year without resetting the current year.

My approach is written below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE years MAXVALUE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM current_date) INCREMENT -12;
SELECT id, EXTRACT (YEAR FROM birthyear)
FROM Health_User
WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM birthyear) IN (years);
```

`birthyear` in `Health_User` is a column in <del>timestamp</del> date format (thanks to Erwin Brandstetter's reminder) which is always January 1st of the year in which the user was born.

However, it returns an error reads: "syntax error at or near 'EXTRACT'" in the first line. Would someone suggest how I can revise my query?

Have read:

- [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createsequence.html)
- [Generate sequence number in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000659/generate-sequence-number-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't create a <strike>[`SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html)</strike> for the purpose of a query. The syntax is also invalid since you cannot pass an *expression* to the utility command. (The reason for the error you see.) It *would* work with dynamic SQL in a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) statement like this:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE years MAXVALUE %s INCREMENT -12', EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now()));
END$$;
```

But not for this purpose. Use [**`generate_series()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) instead:

```
SELECT u.*  -- or just the columns you need
FROM   generate_series(0, 12) g  -- nobody's older than 144 years ...
JOIN   Health_User u ON u.birthyear
                     = (date_trunc('year', now()) - interval '12 years' * g)::date;
```

Works dynamically any time.

This query can use a plain index on `(birthyear)` - while your original cannot, since the predicate is not ["sargable"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable).

Aside:

> `birthyear` in `Health_User` is a column in timestamp format which is always January 1st of the year in which the user was born.

Should be a `date` or a plain `integer`, not a `timestamp`.

Either way, remember that `date_trunc()` and the cast to `date` also depend on the current time zone setting.

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

You can also generate timestamps with `generate_series()` directly. Consider:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Comment: Thanks for your reminders in "Aside". It is indeed in a `date` format. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @ytu: Then cast the expression to `date` accordingly. I added the cast and some links.